# Simple example on using BuildingsPy with Dymola

Tags: python, dymola

I would like to use Python to call my Modelica models using Dymola and BuildingsPy. I read the BuildingsPy tutorial, I understand in general how it goes, but I admit that the examples are not too intuitive for me. Could someone help me with a simple example using for example an existing model in the Modelica library.

Thank you

Comment: @Markus A. Thank you Mrkus, I speak much more French is for that my English is not top

Answer (score 3):

For buildingspy you have to install the following additional python packages:

- numpy
- scipy
- matplotlib (for plotting)

On Windows I recommend to use anaconda for that.

Now you can run a simple simulation as follows:

```
from buildingspy.simulate.Simulator import Simulator
import os

# Make dymola.exe available
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + r"C:\Program Files\Dymola 2019 FD01\bin64"

s = Simulator(modelName="Modelica.Blocks.Examples.PID_Controller", 
              simulator="dymola")

# Simulation settings
s.addParameters({'PI.k': 10.0, 'PI.Ti': 0.1})
s.setNumberOfIntervals(100)
s.setSolver("dassl")
s.setStopTime(3.2)
s.showGUI(show=True)
s.showProgressBar(show=True)

s.simulate()

print("done")
```

When the simulation finishes successful, the python working directory will contain the result file `PID_Controller.mat`.

Now you can use the Reader and Plotter classes to plot results, as described here:
https://simulationresearch.lbl.gov/modelica/buildingspy/io.html

#### Caveats

- The dymola.exe must be available on the system path variable. The code above ensures that.
- buildingspy does not work if a custom working directory is set.

  - In Dymola 2018 FD01 and later: Go to Options > Settings and set *Save startup directory* on *Do not save*

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your explanation, it's really clear and it helped me a lot. I tested one of my models but by launching the code, dymola opens but it does not load the library or my model exists. That's the message I got:

Error: Simulation failed in 'C:\Temp\tmp-simulator-wwuvls\BEE'
   Exception: File C:\Temp\tmp-simulator-wwuvls\BEE\simulator.log does not exist.
   You need to delete the directory manually.

Comment: Answers should not be used to reply. Please have a look at the [Someone Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) help page.
Regarding your problem: It would help to see a minimal example with your problem (maybe in a new question).